# django user update form not updating

Tags: python, django, url, django-views, django-forms

I have a detailed user view that has a button for user updates. The user update form is inside a modal, for that, I am using a `FormView` `ModelForm` and a `TbUser`. I don't get how the form validation works but the fields are correct. When I update something for a user, I get an error, `TbUser with username already exists`, which means the code does not update the user but tries to add a new one. Also, I want to redirect to `user-detail` page after submit.

views.py

```py
class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    template_name = 'users/modals/user_update_modal.html'
    success_message = "User updated successfully."

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kw = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kw['request'] = self.request
        return kw

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        print(obj.username)
        print('valid')
        TbUser.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id).update(username=obj.username, real_name=obj.real_name,
                                                              email=obj.email, cellphone=obj.cellphone,
                                                              department=obj.department, role=obj.role)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, form.errors)
        # Where to redirect here? I want to 

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('user-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.formclass})
```

forms.py

```py
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request
        if request.user.customer:
            self.fields['department'].queryset = TbDepartment.objects.filter(
                customer=request.user.customer)
            self.fields['role'].queryset = TbRole.objects.filter(
                customer=request.user.customer)

    class Meta:
        model = TbUser
        fields = ['username', 'real_name', 'email',
                  'cellphone', 'department', 'role']
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('users-list/', views.UsersListView.as_view(), name='users-list'),
    path('user-detail/<str:pk>/',
         views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user-detail'),
    path('tb-user-update-form/<str:pk>/update/',
         views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name='tb-user-update-form'),
]
```

Comment: Is `TbUser` the user model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `get_object` method to let it point to the object you want to update.

A `FormView` will construct a form *without looking for an object, you can use an [**`UpdateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) to fetch the object with `get_object`, and then inject this in the form to update that object:

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    template_name = 'users/modals/user_update_modal.html'
    success_message = "User updated successfully."

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kw = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kw['request'] = self.request
        return kw

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request.user

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, form.errors)
        return super().form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('user-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk })
```

Comment: it still wants to add a new user throwing the `Tb user with this Username already exists.`. And if its an error it does not redirect to user detail. It redirects to the form without css page.

Comment: is there a inverse for success_url like error_url?

Comment: @Brat: you did remove the `form_valid` method and used an `UpdateView`, right?

Comment: @Brat: typically if there is an error, the `UpdateView` will *rerender* the template with the filled in form and thus show the errors in the form.

Comment: Shouldn't the `UpdateView` be based on a model and not a form?

Comment: I have copy pasted the class and it's saying that user exists with the username

Comment: @Brat: no, you can plugin any `form_class` you want, as long as that form is able to handle a `TbUser` object. By default the `UpdateView` will construct a form that is a standard `ModelForm` for the model, but you can override this behavior by specifying a `form_class`.

Comment: @Brat: can you edit the question and show the full traceback?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236255/discussion-between-brat-and-willem-van-onsem).